# 3d to 2d transformation in opencv

Tags: opencv, camera, transformation, affinetransform, perspectivecamera

I have set of known `3D` points in world coordinate system and I know corresponding `2D` points in the image. 
Now for a new 3D coordinate `(x, y, z)` I need to find the 2D image coordinate `(u, v)` how can I find that in `OpenCV` ?? How can I find transformation matrix (camera matrix, rotation, translation) using `OpenCV` ?

Comment: use calibrateCamera or solvePnp (inverse interpreted). You'll get R and T to use in projectPoints function.

Comment: In solvePnP(), do we need to give camera matrix as input, in documentation its given as input matrix

Comment: @Micka what is difference between calibrateCamera() and solvePnP ?

Comment: I have a lot points in `3D`, but they are in two different parallel planes (since they are in 2 planes that are parallel to ground, i have only 2 `z` values, ie, all the points in one plane have one common `z` value, all the points in other plane have other common `z` value. How many different values  `z` values are required to find `camera/translation/rotation` matrices ?

Comment: I've seen good results on a single plane, but it works best if you know and provide the lens distortion parameters. Otherwise the distortion optimization might bring some mess. If you want to use solcePnP you can try standard camera matrix (principal point in the center of the image and square pixels).

Comment: what  will be `fx` and `fy` values I need to take for camera ?

Comment: try http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#initcameramatrix2d

Comment: thanks @Micka, Do u know how to specify the aspect ratio, I didn't understand it from doc..

Comment: try 1 or 0. Btw, best would be to measure the intrinsics with a test pattern, especially if your lens has some notable distortion

Answer (score 2):

First you need to read about [Fundamental Matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) , and [epipolar geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry)  and understand how projection of world coordinates to image plane is done.

From  the first part of your question it seems you already have this projection matrix. For any new world coordinates just use this matrix.